# how do i unzip stream while reading it in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i read a zip file in my application and i don't want to extract after i read it all ..

i want to extract it while i am reading it.

so how do i extract stream of bytes for a file while i am reading it ?

Comment: As ZIP is a container-format how can you unzip something if you don't wait until the end of the transmission?

Comment: @Select0r, you can because the ZIP format doesn't require you to have the full container before decompressing a single file in the container.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.read.aspx

Comment: @Select0r I suspect the OP is talking about gzip or deflate streams. But given the way the .zip container works it is possible to extract an incomplete file just as far as it has arrived. But I don't know if any .net libraries support that.

Comment: If you understand "zip file" from the question as "gzip stream", okay ... :)

Comment: i am wondering why my question is closed .. while there is people answer this question and i got the answer i want .. if you don't "understand" my question thats your problem

Comment: @peacmaker: No, your inability to ask a question that is answerable is not our problem. Your questions will continue to get closed, no matter how badly you want them answered, as long as you provide insufficient details on what you are trying to accomplish. Several people answered the question, and have since deleted those answers, because it wasn't clear what compression algorithm you were using. You may find this site helpful: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) and [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) classes are wrappers around a normal Stream object. This means that you can extract the data as you're going along before a) the whole file has been downloaded and b) without loading all of the data in to memory.

These are available in .NET 4 upwards, otherwise you'll need to use [#ZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) as suggested.

EDIT:
After looking around it would appear that #ZipLib is definitely the way forwards with this. The same principles apply to these classes in that they are streams, they can work as the file is being downloaded or read over a network and they don't require the whole file to be in memory. I'm currently using it in a project to open zip files from an http server, so I've seen it in action!

Comment: That's true. DeflateStream would be the one to use.

Comment: True that GZIP != ZIP, although they both use the DEFLATE algorithm.

Comment: Actually since it's now clear that the asker wants the ZIP algorithm, both GZipStream and DeflateStream are not useful. He would have to use SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Base Class Library doesn't include classes to stream .zip files.  Take a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are various examples of compression/decompression using the [#Zip](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) library.

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx