# How do you convert a physical zip file to System.IO.Stream object

Tags: c#, stream, zip, converters

How do you convert a physical zip file to System.IO.Stream object?
I tried -

1. `System.IO.Stream stream = File.ReadAllBytes(Path + "\\" + "ZipFile.zip");`
2. `StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Path + "\\" + "ZipFile.zip");`
3. `System.IO.Stream stream = new FileStream(Path + "\\" + "ZipFile.zip", FileMode.Open); stream.Close();`

None of them seems to be working. 
When trying to read the stream it either says the stream is not readable  
 
or the file seems corrupt at the destination and cannot be unzipped

Comment: Using it as a stream would just read it as a stream of bytes, it would have no idea it was a zip file, nor try to decompress it. Could you please provide some code? Have you tried GZipStream or DeflateStream? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4923085/1373170

Answer (score 1):

1. No way to get it to compile (casting `byte[]` to `Stream`)... So not sure how you get runtime error here.
2. `StreamReader` is not a stream - not sure what conversion you expect here.
3. It looks like you immediately close the stream - this seem to be the only line that matches the title and would produce exact runtime error. Fix - don't close the stream till you are done reading from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.For using this code you have to download [dotnetzip-ionic.dll](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

```
using Ionic.Zip;
using Ionic.Crc;
using System.IO;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ZipPath))
    {

        foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
        {

            CrcCalculatorStream reader = entry.OpenReader();
            MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
            reader.CopyTo(memstream);
            byte[] bytes = memstream.ToArray();
            System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes); 


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 on the recommendation to use DotNetZip, pretty straigh-forward tool for Zip files management.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ZipInputStream` from SharpZipLib:  https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/593036/301152